# PostAsync is not a member of HttpClient

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I have used the following code before without any issues. Now I am getting :

```
PostAsync is not a member of HttpClient
```

I have made sure that the relevant references are present, and that all Imports are in place (Imports System.Net.Http).

I am using .Net Framework 4.5, I have also tried 4.5.1 but to no avail.

```
Public Shared Async Function PostTrx(ByVal baseURI As String, ByVal code As String, ByVal account As String, ByVal serial As String, ByVal dest As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()

    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent({New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("response", code), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("account", account), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("sn", serial), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("mode", dest)})
    Dim response = Await client.PostAsync(baseURI, content)
    Dim stringContent = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Return stringContent
End Function
```

Comment: In Solution Explorer, in the Project tree, open up `References`, click on `System.Net.Http` and, in the Properties panel, take note of the `Path`, `Resolved` and `Runtime version` values of the assembly. Post them here.

Comment: @Jimi Path and Runtime Version are empty and Resolved in False.

Comment: So, you don't have a reference to the `System.Net.Http` assembly. Remove all references. Go to `Project Properties-> References` and remove the reference there, the verify it's beed removed from the Project References tree. Build the project (some errors might raise; comment out and move on). Then add back the reference using the `Project -> References -> Add Reference` context menu. Verify the file location of the assembly. Possibly, install .Net Framework `4.7.1` or `4.7.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by appending "Http." before HttpClient, so your code would look like:

```
Public Shared Async Function PostTrx(ByVal baseURI As String, ByVal code As String, ByVal account As String, ByVal serial As String, ByVal dest As String) As Task(Of String)
    Dim client As Http.HttpClient = New Http.HttpClient()

    Dim content = New FormUrlEncodedContent({New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("response", code), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("account", account), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("sn", serial), New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("mode", dest)})
    Dim response = Await client.PostAsync(baseURI, content)
    Dim stringContent = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    Return stringContent
End Function
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: With the correct using statement this using be necessary.